# Real issue installing Kit Op free for 2.91+

Tags: materials

I am using Blender 3.2 and I am trying to use the Cycles EEVEE materials system that I purchased.

According to the developer Kit Op free is included.  I watched the how to videos and followed them to the letter and installing from preferences/addon does nothing.  No kitop, no files or .py files in the zip files I downloaded.

I downloaded Kit ops free and tried that, again nothing.

I have installed multiple addons so I know how to do it.  The zip files contain nothing that even vaguely looks like an addon.  It's all materials libraries.  You can't use it unless the addon is installed.  I have tried nine ways to Sunday and nothing works.  The Kit Ops free is for v2.91+, so I would assume that means everything from 2.81 up.

I looked for some way to contact the developer directly and could not find anything.  I am asking here just in case someone knows what the hell is going on.  At the very least does anyone know how to contact chippwalters?

I bought the plugin and he made tutorials so I guess he has some sort of support in place, but I can't find it.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Ok... I did.  The issue was getting Kit Op to install in Blender.  Are you really not able to see that I asked a question and fleshed out the problem in my description.  I write very well.  I just wanted to get an answer not criticism.  Not cool at all.

Comment: https://www.chippwalters.com/support

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I tried reply to my receipt email... its says to do that if you have questions but I haven't heard anything so far.  Thanks again.